# Semicode OS is not Installing

Tags: linux

SemiCode Os is not installing whenever I Choose "Install Directly" option from GRUB it just Run As Live and further it doesn't give any Install Option
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not installing"? Does computer hang? Are there any messages? What are you doing to install it? Which stage fails?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Not insatlling means Semicode OS Beta version(Linux Distro based on Ubuntu 14 ) not installing on MY Hard Drive(computer)   When I Try to install it with bootable pendrive ...it boot the GRUB ...then i choose to "Install" option given in GRUB..then it does not install ..just "Run AS Live "...No Error msg ,computer does not hang ...."IT JUST AS LIVE" instead Installing..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that at this point in time, semicode os beta 0.1 have a bug that leads directly to live cd instead of the installer as stated here https://github.com/semicode-ltd/semicodeosdocs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the beta version cannot be installed. its sill on development stage and not ready for install. Still you can try the OS and can support the development team with live preview.